# Entity Framework Code First Migrations Error on published Asp.net MVC IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have created an `asp.net` `mvc` Project that is using the Entity Framework Code first. Migrations are enabled. 
When I deploy Project on `IIS`, the migrations error that occurs is:

> Migrations is enabled for context *'MyContext'* but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using this putting in your global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
        using (MyContext temp = new MyContext())
        {
            temp.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, I solved it like this:

1. In the constructor of your Configuration class turn off the migration:

`public Configuration()
 {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
 }`

2. Drop the table `__MigrationHistory`from your production database.